# How to configure Ubuntu to use specific graphics card for Xorg Server, from a Hybrid graphics card system?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg

We are using Ubuntu 20.04 on Xeon E Intel.
Monitor is connected through VGA to internal Intel graphics card.

We want to use Nvidia Tesla T4 for AI application ( no monitor connected ).
When I install NVidia cuda drivers Ubuntu stops using the internal graphics card and I can't see login screen at startup, only an initial screen and then stops updating it. On Bios menu internal graphics card is selected as primary.

How can I configure Xorg for this setup? I want Ubuntu to use the internal graphics card for Xorg.
Thank you

Comment: this doesn't happen on Ubuntu 18.04 so it appears to be a bug on Ubuntu 20.04 only !